# How to identify if user has entered invalid pin in device credentials page

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I would like to show custom lock screen specific to app if the user has entered the wrong device credentials(PIN/Pattern/Password) 3 times.

I have tried with AuthenticationFailed() using BiometricPrompt and onActivityResult using createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent().

Both are conveying if the user has cancelled the flow but not the invalid credentials.

Is there any call back methods which will identify the wrong pin entry?